# Текст не окрашивается и не меняет размера

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
         <head>
              <meta charset = "UTF-8"/>
              <link href = "styles2.css" rel = "stylesheets" type = "text/css"/>
         </head>

         <body>

         </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Не stylesheets, а stylesheet. И не ставьте пробелы вокруг =

Comment: А можно ответить не сюда, чтобы я мог закрыть это.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо stylesheets нужно было написать stylesheet. Спасибо, andreymal.